# Xperia X F5121 won't boot past splash screen

Tags: twrp, fastboot, android-10, sony-xperia

I'd appreciated any feedback on the below.

I followed this https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/rom-10-0-aosp-suzu-sonyxperiadev-q-builds.3969967/ thread about upgrading Xperia X F5121 from Android 8 to 10.

After going through the steps my phone is stuck on the splash screen with SONY logo. Won't boot further.

I used TWRP to wipe data, system, Darwik and cache, then flashed custom ROM, then I used fastboot to flash oem binaries, then flashed Gapps and rebooted.

Where did I probably go wrong ?

Comment: https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=4015131

Comment: I followed the guide and instead of screen with Sony the phone just keeps rebooting now. It's interesting to see how the same guide can work differently for people. Some people are successful and some end up with splash screen.

Comment: that depends on base. working device is required, furthermore rom version mismatch may be cause of trouble. try older oem partition (android 9). also check dm-verity

Comment: So I've tried like 50 different builds from XDA threads. Each of them resulted either with my phone stuck on splash screen or phone keeps rebooting. TWRP keeps saying "no OS found". The latest I've tried is this https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/rom-unofficial-aosp9r46-pie-aosp10r41-x-x-dualsim-x-compact-2020-11-01-builds.4004959/ which people in the thread are praising.

Comment: I've managed to get stock ROM back on the phone. It boots past the splash screen
but the "XPERIA" animation keeps looping forever.

Comment: either restore all partitions to stock (including recovery) or disable avb/dm-verity and fix encryption